# Problema de georeferenciacion

Tags: pyqgis

Tengo problemas para georeferenciar coordenadas obtenidas con GoogleMaps en una capa llamada Parcelas.

El ejemplo concretamente es que mi capa Parcelas tiene la siguiente especificacion según QGis:

“Extensión:

En unidades del sistema espacial de referencia de la capa: xMín,yMín 2.53729e+06,6.47876e+06 : xMáx,yMáx 2.55872e+06,6.51084e+06

Sistema de referencia espacial de la capa:

+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs SRID 4326”

Las coordenadas del punto que quisiera georeferenciar, según google son: -31.57629, -68.54670.

En mi capa Parcela, ese punto tiene las coordenadas: 2543130.5, 6507208.2

He buscado todos los conversores y con ninguno he podido efectuar una conversion que me arroje datos similares. Lo extraño es que mi capa tiene el mismo sistema de coordenadas que GoogleMaps.

Llevo mucho tiempo tratando de resolver este problema, por favor si alguien puede ayudarme estare agradecido.